# Do I have to use the past continuous or the past perfect?

Tags: grammar, tense, past-tense

I’m working on mixed tenses exercises, and this sentence has confused me! I’d like to know whether my answer is correct or not please. This is the sentence:

> “For the first eight years, she worked in the sales department, and .....(to work) there when I .....(to become) the managing director.”

This is my answer:

> “For the first eight years, she worked in the sales department, and she was working there when I became the managing director.”

Comment: Your sentence is fine, although you don't need the second "she".  However unless you can add more detail why this structure is confusing, I think the question should be closed.

Comment: Thank you:) I  was just wondering if saying “she had been working there when I had become the managing director” would be more correct ?